# macro expansion to additional macro arguments

Tags: c, macros, arguments

I'm looking for a way of making a macro that expands to extra arguments:

```
int constant1=2, constant2=3;
#define add_three_arguments(x,y,z) x+y+z
#define extra_arguments ,constant1,constant2
#define make_value(A) add_three_arguments(A extra_arguments)

int r = make_value(5);
```

Comment: Why you want a macro while you can surely use a function to do that?

Comment: Not directly related, bit __never__ define macros like `#define add_three_arguments(x,y,z) x+y+z` but always put the expression into `()` like this: `#define add_three_arguments(x,y,z) (x+y+z)`. Otherwise if you use `x = add_three_arguments(1,2,3) * 10` the result will not be what you expect.

Comment: It would really help if you would tell us the higher-level goal you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution I have found is this:

```
int constant1=2, constant2=3;
#define _add_three_arguments(x,y,z) x+y+z
#define add_three_arguments(...) _add_three_arguments(__VA_ARGS__)

#define extra_arguments ,constant1,constant2
#define make_value(A) add_three_arguments(A extra_arguments)

int r = make_value(5);
```

Which is of course not a solution to the problem I stated.  So the current answer seems to be, "this is not possible."  But maybe a new version of clang/gcc will somehow enable this.  I will leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#define EMPTY
#define EVAL(X) X
#define add_three_arguments(x,y,z) x+y+z
#define extra_arguments ,constant1,constant2
#define make_value(A) EVAL(add_three_arguments EMPTY (A extra_arguments))

make_value(5);
```

However, if you redesign your macros you may get a nicer solution not requiring such constructs.